# Specify object location in a JSON object graph to JsonConvert

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

In a JSON received like so:

```
{ name { first_name: 'Foo', last_name: 'Bar' }, emails: [ {value: 'foo@bar.com' } ]
```

Is there a way to tell JsonConvert to, for example:

1. Fetch the `value` property of the first element of the `emails` array into the POCO property `Email` below?
2. Read the `first_name` property from the `name` object in JSON and put it in the `FirstName` property of the POCO below?

I have tried doing this kind of a path but that doesn't work. Is there a syntax for this?

```
public class DaPOCO
{
  [JsonProperty("name.first_name")]
  public FirstName { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("emails[0].value")]
  public Email { get; set;} 
}
```

I know, failing short of a syntax, I could read the properties myself from a dynamic object like so:

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeseralizeObject(json);
DaPOCO poco = new DaPOCO
{
  FirstName = data.name.first_name;
  Email = data.emails?.ElementAt(0)?.value;
};
```

I was just wondering if there was an in-built attribute-based syntax to do this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your posted serialized json, below should be the correct models to be deserialized to. I believe you understand that the current model is not compatible with the json you have

```
public class Name
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class DaPOCO
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
    public List<Email> emails { get; set; }
}
```

You can try something like below

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string responseString = @"{ name: { first_name: 'Foo', last_name: 'Bar' }, emails: [ {value: 'foo@bar.com' } ] }";
        JObject jo = JObject.Parse(responseString);
        JObject obj = (jo["emails"] as JArray).FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value<string>("value"))) as JObject;
        DaPOCO poco = new DaPOCO
        {
            FirstName = ((jo["name"] as JObject)["first_name"]).ToString(),
            Email = obj["value"].ToString(),
        };

        Console.WriteLine(poco.FirstName + "\t" + poco.Email);
    }
}

public class DaPOCO
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. But I was wondering if there was a way to specify a path like syntax to the newtonsoft deserializer?

Comment: Well, not really what I am asking but since you're putting in so much of effort, I will mark this answer as the right one for now until someone hits the target point-blank. My question is not really -- what do I do now? How do I go about deserializing the object.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 no don't mark it as answer if that's not what question point to.